# Pass function to completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

I have a function that performs an animation on a view. I would like to implement a completion handler for this function that would be called after the animation is complete.

In ViewController...

```
hudView.hide(animated: true, myCompletionHandler: {
    // Animation is complete
})
```

In HudView class...

```
func hide(animated: Bool, myCompletionHandler: () -> Void) {
    if animated {
        transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: [], animations: {
            self.alpha = 0
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: nil) // I want to run 'myCompletionHandler' in this completion handler
    }
}
```

I've tried a number of things but can't find the correct syntax:

```
}, completion: myCompletionHandler)
```

> Passing non-escaping parameter 'myCompletionHandler' to function expecting an
>   @escaping closure

```
}, completion: myCompletionHandler())
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'Void' to expected argument type '((Bool)
>   -> Void)?'

```
}, completion: { myCompletionHandler() })
```

> Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'myCompletionHandler' may allow it to
>   escape

As a swift novice these error messages don't mean very much to me and I cant seem to find any examples of the correct way to do this.

What is the correct way to pass `myCompletionHandler` to the `.animate` completion handler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to pass your own closure as an input argument to `UIView.animate`, you need to match the types of the closures, so `myCompletionHandler` has to have a type of `((Bool) -> ())?`, just like `completion`.

```
func hide(animated: Bool, myCompletionHandler: ((Bool) -> ())?) {
    if animated {
        transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: [], animations: {
            self.alpha = 0
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: myCompletionHandler) // I want to run 'myCompletionHandler' in this completion handler
    }
}
```

This is how you can call it:

```
hudView.hide(animated: true, myCompletionHandler: { success in
    //animation is complete
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to use completion in UIView.animate :

```
func hide(animated: Bool, myCompletionHandler: () -> Void) {
    if animated {
        transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: [], animations: {
            self.alpha = 0
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: { (success) in
            myCompletionHandler()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Damien. But this throws a compiler error: `Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'myCompletionHandler' may allow it to escape`

Answer (score 0):

```
You can create your function as,

func hide(_ animated:Bool, completionBlock:((Bool) -> Void)?){

}

And you can call it as,

self.hide(true) { (success) in
   // callback here     
}
```

Comment: This gives me: `@escaping attribute only applies to function types`